# Duda con una edición hecha por un usuario a otro OP

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Como podrán ver en el siguiente ejemplo
El usuario James Fernández hizo su pregunta
Ahora, el usuario Nico, [sugiere una edicion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/298092) y acá es donde entra mi duda.

El comentario de Nico dice:

> Me dado cuenta que no se hace con el instance

Y procede a editar el código original del OP...
Esto no es más bien el comentario o respuesta que el mismo debería dar ???
Por que, a mi parecer, está editando tratando de dar solución a un problema.
Y como se yo que el problema del OP es ese o no ?

Dejo la edición a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo la marqué como "*intenta responder*" rechazándola o eso es lo que veo jeje, el comentario que puso el usuario en su edición me dice que es una respuesta.

Comment: Pero entonces, es correcta mi interpretación, si es como si tratase de responder la pregunta, pero editandola.

Comment: Si al menos creo que ambos así lo interpretamos.

Comment: Lo mismo es la misma persona

Comment: Es la misma persona ?? Pero no se ven personas, se ven usuarios...

Comment: Si podría ser de esas personas que crean otro usuario para hacer la edición o simplemente ya no pudo iniciar sesión con su anterior usuario, pero cuando suele pasar eso el nombre de usuario suele ser similar y en este caso son completamente diferentes.

Comment: rechazo directo... no se si es una respuesta o que, pero por lo menos daña la publicacion original...

Comment: @Israel-ICM ohh entiendo, de todos modos, no deberia intervernir en la otra cuenta, por lo que deberia inicar de nuevo la pregunta y notificar de la duplicacion y el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi eso interpretaba, pero me parecia un caso muy peculiar y queria asegurarme.

Comment: Alterar el código original desvirtúa la pregunta, pues ahora se refiere a algo que ya no existe.